# iBatis : could execute() trigger other events?

Tags: java, spring, ibatis

I'm maintaining an old Spring project which uses iBatis.

I can see some JMS messages are sent to a certain server, when the debugger finishes executing this method :

```
getSqlMapClientTemplate().execute(
  executor.startBatch();
  executor.insert(someDTO);
  executor.executeBatch();
  return null;
);
```

But the problem is that **I cannot find how the messages are sent**. It's not in the callback, neither is there a AOP method related to this (I checked all xml).

I wonder what other possibilities could trigger method invoking when executing iBatis executor ?

Comment: Is the JMS message sent from your code, or maybe from a trigger on the database server?

Comment: I'm not famaliar with database server triggering, but as we use Oracle db I don't think the trigger in DB level could generate JMS event

Comment: Why do you think that? Oracle itself provides AQ, which supports a JMS implementation, it can also run - for example - Java-based stored procedures. In theory, anything that you can do from your code could also be done from the Oracle database.

Comment: No I searched everywhere and do not find any database trigger in any of scripts